# How to offer a chooser to get content for multiple mime types?

Tags: android

I want to have one button in my app that lets the user pick images or any other files from the apps on the device. Here's the code in my activity for letting the user pick files from apps such as Dropbox and Drive:

```
    private static int RESULT_GET_CONTENT = 1;

    public void getFileContent() {
        Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        fileIntent.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(fileIntent, RESULT_GET_CONTENT);
    }
```

That brings up a list of the available apps. When the user chooses one that app lets him browse the files.

To pick images from the Gallery I can change the intent's type to `"image/*"`.

How do I change this to bring up a list of apps that includes files apps (Dropbox & Drive) and image apps (Gallery)?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that the solution is very simple. I just needed to use "*/*" as the type and then add the openable category which filters out things like contacts that I don't want.

```
public void getFileContent() {
    Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    fileIntent.setType("*/*");
    fileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(fileIntent, RESULT_GET_CONTENT);
}
```